# using a batch file, searching an ini file within a specific section, then within a specific name= to read a specific value

Tags: batch-file, ini

Basically I've been able to grab an ini file by doing a REG Query (using all possible registry keys for the application) to discover the location and then set the directory as a variable

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
echo=%StyleDir%
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
echo=%StyleDir%
cd %StyleDir%
```

The next part is where I'd like to search through the "Style.ini" file and get the value for SQLiteHome=

Here are the first several lines of the **Default** Style.ini:

```
    [Default]
    DataHome=C:\ProgramData\Zephyr\Data
    SQLiteHome=c:\programdata\zephyr\data
    [DataBaseList]
    DbsId=Stl,Ind,Fnd,Set,Isa,Zin,Mng
```

So in this case, I'd like to set a variable to become (the value of SQLiteHome), c:\programdata\zephyr\data.

Been googling all over the place, and I've had varying results (one of which included replacing the entire contents of the ini file with "SQLiteHome". Anyway. If I could figure out how to just **echo** the above c:\programdata\zephyr\data. Then I could use that as a template to continue my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findstr` to pick out the correct line from the ini, then `for /f` to parse it, similar to what you did with REG.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr SQLiteHome style.ini') do set SQLiteHome=%%a
```

Comment: and now I feel like an idiot.....

but thank you, been working on it on and off for about 2 weeks now.